# querying flags recursively in database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a hierarchy of `Article`, and each `Article` has a property `IsCommentable`.  This can take a value of true, false, or NULL.  If it is NULL, it means that it inherits the value based on it's parents.  Articles can be nested recursively, and there is no limit to the 'depth'.

Now, I need to make a query where I get all the articles from a database which are commentable.  Is there any way these can be loaded via an SQL query?

Comment: What database are you using?  You have a chance with SQL Server (as per Yuxiu Li's answer) or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, You can do it with a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

```
WITH cte (id, iscommentable) AS (
  SELECT id, iscommentable FROM Article WHERE iscommentable IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a1.id, a2.iscommentable FROM Article a1
  INNER JOIN cte a2 ON a1.parent=a2.id
  WHERE a1.iscommentable IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

SQL fiddle [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0475f/2/0).

Comment: I am using MySQL - which I guess does not support such a query.

Comment: I'm not an expert in MySQL, but if it's not possible to write a recursive query, you can try to do a stored procedure that calculates iteratively. Performance may suffer for very deep nesting though.

Comment: Thats my problem, with deep nesting performance suffers a lot - especially if the query can get called quite some times.